# How this canvas function input is incrementing from undefined?

Tags: function, canvas, null, rotation, undefined

I came across this canvas rotation on Code Pen. The input variable **step** received no value, but as soon as requestAnimationFrame starts to run, **step** leaves the state of undefined and modify *angle* that should be NaN, how this happened?
**[Canvas Rotation - Code Pen](http://codepen.io/Budachev/pen/LqyBr?editors=1111)**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var canvasWidth = canvas.width; 
var canvasHeight = canvas.height; 
var cx = canvasWidth/2;
var cy = canvasHeight/2;
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function draw(step){
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  
  context.fillStyle = "deepskyblue";
  context.fillRect(0,0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  
  context.save();
   
  context.translate(cx, cy);
  var angle = step * 0.001; //HOW STEP GOT VALUE?
  context.rotate(angle);
  context.fillStyle = "tomato";
  context.fillRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
  
  context.restore();
  
}

 requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<canvas width="320" height="240" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: rAF passes an HighResTimestamp in your callback. [Read the docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `requestAnimationFrame` method with pass an argument to the given callback:

From the [documentation](https://devdocs.io/dom/window/requestanimationframe):

> The callback method is passed a single argument, a
>   DOMHighResTimeStamp, which indicates the current time when callbacks
>   queued by requestAnimationFrame() begin to fire. [...]

In this case it will be assigned to `step`.